# 403 forbidden dont have permission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, xampp

i am working on laravel web app to upload images into datatable and download that image on click it worked fine(( but i want the uploaded image to be downloaded on click ) until i change the code from  `return '{!! Html::link('images/u4.png', 'Download') !!}';`  to   `return '{!! Html::link('images/.$doc->image', 'Download') !!}';` and the i am getting this error [forbidden dont have permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4VNx.png)
i am using xampp localhost
my code for your understanding where i am stuck
index.blade.php

```
 columns: [
            // render:function(data,type,full,meta){
            //     return '<a href="'+data.filepath+'/'+data.fileName + '" download>Download</a>' 
            // },
            // "targets": 0
          // { data: 'rownum', orderable: false, searchable: false },
            { data: 'doc_type', name: 'doc_type' },                                              
            { data: 'doc_number', name: 'doc_number' },
            { data: 'doc_date', name: 'doc_date'},                                              
            { data: 'amount', name: 'amount' },  
                                                        
            { data: 'currency', name: 'currency' },                                              
            { data: 'partener', name: '{{ TBL_PARTENER }}.id'}, 
            { data: 'image', name: 'image',render:function(data,type,full,meta){
                // return '<a href="'+data.filepath+'/'+data.fileName + '" download="myImage">Download</a>' 
                // return '<a href="/images/.$doc->image" download >Download</a>' 
                 return '{!! Html::link('images/.$doc->image', 'Download') !!}';
                 //  return '{!! Html::link('images/u4.png', 'Download') !!}';
             } }, 
            
            //'image' => ['name' => 'image', 'data' => 'image'],                                   
            { data: 'comments', name: 'comments' },            
            { data: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}        
        ],
```

DocumentsController

```
 public function download($file){
    $file_path = public_path('images/'.$file);
    return response()->download( $file_path);
}
```

// this code is written in store method

$this->validate($request, [

```
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:6048',
]);
$doc = new Document($request->input()) ;

if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {
   
   $file = $request->file('image') ;
   
   $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
   $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
   $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
   $doc->image = $fileName ;
```

}

Route

```
Route::get('/images/{file}','DocumentsController@download');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have generate a wrong route brother. In the screenshot you have attacked the URL on the browser is `localhost/conta/public/images/$doc->image` which is not a valid route that's why apache throws "Forbidden Error".

Generating a valid url may solve your issue.

Comment: s how i can write a right route please help as i am very new to this

Comment: i have removed $doc->image then it navigate me to the images folder and shows me list of images